# Looking for book I read in the '80s about a hart/unicorn

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult, unicorns

I thought I remembered reading a book in the '80s called *The Last Hart*. If I recall correctly, the story took place in modern times and was from the perspective of human young adults, not the hart/unicorn. I have not been able to locate it. Perhaps I have the title wrong. Anyone ever heard of it?

Comment: This sounds interesting but is somewhat vague -- can you remember any more details?

Comment: Unfortunately no

Answer (score 6):

Could this be *[The Transfigured Hart](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/39297255-the-transfigured-hart)* (1975) by Jane Yolen?

> **Is what Richard saw in the woods really a unicorn?**
>
> Heather and Richard have little in common. A voracious reader growing up in a large house filled with books, Richard is a sickly child that spends most of his time alone or surrounded by adults. Heather is comfortable in a crowd, but nonetheless sneaks away on her appaloosa pony for lone adventures in woods.
>
> One evening after dinner, Richard spies a strange, white deer in the fading light of the woods. It leaps away into the thick brush, but Richard is certain of what he’s seen: a unicorn. And Heather—out for a ride on her pony—has also spotted the unusual hart.
>
> When Heather and Richard meet, they cannot agree on what they’ve encountered, and they definitely do not want to share their secret. But they will soon discover that their mutual help is indeed much-needed.
>
> [image]